# Plot mean and standard deviation by category

Tags: r, plot, mean

I'm trying to plot a plot with mean and sd bars by three levels of a factor.

(After two hours of searching on the internet, then checking the Rbook and Rgraphs book I'm still not finding the answer. I think this is because it is a very simple question.)

I have a simple data frame with three columns: my categories, mean, sd.

I would like to do a plot with the mean by category and its sd bars, just like 
[this one (edit: link broken)](http://www.talkstats.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1655&stc=1&d=1324633172)

My dataframe looks like this

```
  color     mean.temp      sd        
  black     37.93431      2.267125        
  red       37.01423      1.852052        
  orange    36.61345      1.339032
```

I'm so sorry for asking this dumb question but I sincerely couldn't find any simple answer to my simple question.

Comment: maybe this helps (if you don't mind using ggplot2): http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `data.frame` holding your data:

```
foo <- data.frame(color=c("black","red","orange"),
    mean.temp=c(37.93431,37.01423,36.61345),
    sd=c(2.267125,1.852052,1.339032))
```

Now, we first plot the means as dots, making sure that we have enough room horizontally (`xlim`) and vertically (`ylim`), suppressing x axis annotation (`xaxt="n"`) and all axis labeling (`xlab="", ylab=""`).

```
plot(1:3,foo$mean.temp,pch=19,xlab="",ylab="",xaxt="n",xlim=c(0.5,3.5),
    ylim=c(min(foo$mean.temp-foo$sd),max((foo$mean.temp+foo$sd))))
```

Next, we plot the standard deviations as lines. You could also use three separate `lines` commands, which may be easier to read. This way, we first collect the data into matrices via `rbind()`. R will automatically turn these matrices into vectors and recycle them. The `NA`s are there so we don't join the end of one line to the beginning of the next one. (Try removing the NAs to see what happens.)

```
lines(rbind(1:3,1:3,NA),rbind(foo$mean.temp-foo$sd,foo$mean.temp+foo$sd,NA))
```

Finally, annote the x axis:

```
axis(side=1,at=1:3,labels=foo$color)
```

[image: means with sds]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, excellent step by step explanation. Was exactly what I needed. Is there a way to add to each line the classic "flat arrows"?

Comment: I used the function "arrows" instead of "lines" and I did this: arrows(c(1,2,3), foo$mean.temp+foo$sd, c(1,2,3), foo$mean.temp-foo$sd, code=3, angle=90, length=0.05).

Again, thank you for your kindness and detailed explanation

Answer (score 19):

With `ggplot`:

**read data**:

```
df=read.table(text=' color mean.temp   sd
1 black 37.93431 2.267125

2 red 37.01423 1.852052

3 orange 36.61345 1.339032',header=TRUE)
```

**plotting:**

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=color, y=mean.temp)) + 
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean.temp-sd, ymax=mean.temp+sd), width=.2) +
     geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

**output**

[image]